# SQL Server Engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am about to purchase developer edition for my local machine.  My team will get a development server for development.  I would like to find out if the developer edition that I'm going to purchase will come with the SQL Server (2012) Engine that I can install on the development server so I can connect to databases on the development server through my local Management Studio?  Each one in my team will eventually get his/her developer edition so we will all connect to the same databases.

Second question is I have a trial version of 2012 installed.  How do I find out how much longer for the trial?  And how do I enter the serial number once I purchase the license for this version?

Please advise!  Thanks!

Comment: SO is NOT MS support forum, nor is it their sales forum.

Comment: Even if it were either of those two things, which it is not, you also asked two unrelated questions. Unrelated questions should be asked separately in two different posts (if they were on-topic for SO, which again, they aren't, so don't repost either of them in this case.)

Comment: You better talk to a Microsoft sales rep. He/she will be happy to answer your questions. SQL Server license ain't cheap.

Comment: I'm actually going to buy the software from somewhere other than Microsoft for a cheaper price.  But the sales person is not technical enough to answer my questions..that's why I posted it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can purchase developer editions versions of SQL Server for each one of your developers and install it (create an instance) on each machine. You can install an instance on a central machine. Are you going to do both? As long as it is being used for development you can install it but I would check if Microsoft sales. If each developer has their own instance you are going to have quite a nightmare maintaining a single version of all the different objects (tables/indexes/procedures/functions and more) the developers are going to create. The quality of the objects and how security aware they are will vary greatly. You will end up with a lot of embedded SQL instead of procedures.  You will have multiple tables that contain the same date because it will be too hard to get anyone to compromise. What you need to do is to anoint someone as the dba who everyone has to coordinate with or else you will have very funny/sad/insane stories to share.

Comment: I would like each developer to be able to connect to the development database server so all developers should be able to query the same databases from that server on his/her local machine.  I just want to find out which version of the SQL Server should be installed on the development server.  I heard the developer edition comes with the engine that can be installed on the development server too.  I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: Dev edition is an enterprise version, fully,  featured version of SQL Server.It has everything you need. Still think that someone in your team needs to become the dba.

Comment: I have obtained the developer edition today.  Should I remove my current trial version of the enterprise full version?  Do I need to backup all current databases so they can be restored after I install the developer version?

Comment: If the dev version is the same, or higher then the trial no problem restoring the backed up dbs. You know it's customary to mark answers if they have been useful?